# Cannot use aws-azure-login from within Docker container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, docker

I am working on a remote server, where I generally use aws-azure-login by:

```
aws-azure-login -p profile_name --mode cli --no-prompt --force-refresh
```

(I have a .aws folder in my home folder, with a config file containing the configuration for the different profiles).

However, I need to run my system from a Docker container. The [github page](https://github.com/aws-azure-login/aws-azure-login) states that you can install aws-azure-login by installing Nodejs and puppeteer, so I created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

# disable potential manual input requiremnts during the installations (tzdata)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update --fix-missing && \
        apt install python3-pip -y && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# install Nodejs and puppeterr for aws-azure-login
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm --verbose i puppeteer
RUN npm install -g --verbose aws-azure-login --unsafe-perm
```

I successfully built the image and ran the container, mounting the local .aws folder inside of it:

```
docker run -it --privileged --gpus all -v /home/username/.aws/:/root/.aws/ container_name
```

but if I try using aws-azure-login from within the container, I get the following error:

```
Using AWS SAML endpoint https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:231:68)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Interface.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:534:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:260:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it might be helpful to anyone, I was able to fix it by changing the Docker  file to this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

# disable potential manual input requiremnts during the installations (tzdata)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update --fix-missing && \
        apt install python3-pip -y && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
        ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# starting with NodeJS version 15, when no WORKDIR is specified, npm install is executed in the root directory of
# the container, which results in errors
WORKDIR /usr/app

# install Nodejs and puppeterr for aws-azure-login
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm --verbose i puppeteer
RUN npm install -g --verbose aws-azure-login --unsafe-perm
```